# How to convert array of char into array of int?

Tags: arrays, c, embedded

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stats.h"

/* Size of the Data Set */
#define SIZE (40)

void print_array (unsigned char *p, int l) {
    int i;  
    for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
        printf("%d\t",*p);
        p++;    
    }
    
}
void print_array_int (int *p, int l) {
    int i;  
    for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
        printf("%d\t",*p);
        p++;    
    }
    
}
void typecasting(unsigned char test[SIZE], int array[SIZE]) {
    int i=0;
    unsigned char *token = strtok(test,",");
    while (token) {
        if(i<SIZE) {
        array[i++] = atoi(token);
        }
    token = strtok(NULL,",");
    }
}
void main() {
  int array[SIZE] = {};
  unsigned char test[SIZE] = {34,201,190,154,8,194,2,6,114,88,45,76,123,87,25,23,200,122,150,90,92,87,177,244,201,6,12,60,8,2,5,67,7,87,250,230,99,3,100,90};



  /* Other Variable Declarations Go Here */
  /* Statistics and Printing Functions Go Here */
print_array(test, SIZE);
typecasting(test,array);
print_array_int(array,SIZE);
}
```

What I want in this code is to convert the array of char into an array of int.
Previously I tried doing this by using pointers but didn't work and it showed stack smashing error. I want to convert this array of char into array of int to perform some mathematical operations.

Comment: Before going any further, its likely prudent to research the difference between C#/C++/C because you seem to be confused

Comment: What do you mean by convert? If it is just preserve the numerical value, strtok and atoi have no place here.  Just do a for(;i<SIZE:++i)array[i]=test[i]; instead of everything in typecasting that comes after the int i=0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying too hard. Here's how typecasting should look

```
void typecasting(unsigned char test[SIZE], int array[SIZE]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        array[i] = test[i];
}
```

Your code might be suitable if you were converting from a C string, i.e. if your original test array was

```
char test[] = "34,201,190,154,8,194,2,6,114,88,45,76,123,87,25,23,...";
```

So I guess you could say you're misunderstanding the nature of `char` (and `unsigned char`) in C++. They can represent character data as in `char greeting[] = "hello";` or they can represent small integers as in `char test[] = {1,2,3};`.

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you very much. I was pretty exhausted and couldnt get my brain right on it.

Comment: Hello @abbasalit987, if this answered your question please mark it as accepted, that would give you and the answerer some points and inprove reputation.